# eclipse checkstyle error cannot initialize module TreeWalker - TreeWalker is not allowed as a parent of FileLength

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle

I get the following error when I try to load a user defined check style template.

```
cannot initialize module TreeWalker - TreeWalker is not allowed as a parent of FileLength
```

I think it might be due to the incompatibilty with checkstyle version in my eclipse.
How will I be able to find the appropriate checkstyle version with checkstyle xml file

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is an error in the template, independent of the Checkstyle version. `FileLength` goes directly under `Checker`, not under `TreeWalker`.

Example:

```xml
<module name="Checker">
    <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <property name="tabWidth" value="4"/>
        <module name="JavadocType"/>
        <!-- many others -->
    </module>
    <module name="NewlineAtEndOfFile"/>
    <module name="FileLength"/>
    <module name="JavadocPackage"/>
    <!-- others -->
</module>
```

Comment: I don't know how you answered this question correctly in 2013, because Checkstyle introduced it as a breaking change in the release notes for [September 1, 2019](https://checkstyle.org/releasenotes.html#Release_8.24). Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Dang, and I take so much care not to change the past when time-traveling! @noumenon

Comment: Or maybe it was *FileLength*, not *LineLength* ...  @noumenon

Comment: Well, hats off to Google for getting me that close when I searched for LineLength. This helped!